# ClassNotFoundException - Ionic Plugin

Tags: android, ionic4

I'm having trouble running a custom plugin in android (ios is working fine). The plugin I'm trying to run is [cordova-plugin-measure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-measure).

When I try to run the plugin on Android it gives me the following error message:

```
15 14:22:51.300 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gj.arcoredraw.MeasurePlugin
2021-12-15 14:22:51.300 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.300 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.300 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.300 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:539)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.301 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:176)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.301 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:129)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.302 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.302 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gj.arcoredraw.MeasurePlugin" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~s1e0f1KoKb8qJX9A_yYsew==/com.proyectoterra.instaladores-Z4nedDqeyFz7Tih_s6HUoQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~s1e0f1KoKb8qJX9A_yYsew==/com.proyectoterra.instaladores-Z4nedDqeyFz7Tih_s6HUoQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/~~s1e0f1KoKb8qJX9A_yYsew==/com.proyectoterra.instaladores-Z4nedDqeyFz7Tih_s6HUoQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.303 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:  ... 12 more
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores I/System.out: Error adding plugin com.gj.arcoredraw.MeasurePlugin.
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:178)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:129)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
2021-12-15 14:22:51.304 9231-9348/com.proyectoterra.instaladores W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

My source files look fine in the `plugin.xml` under android:

```
<platform name="android" kotlin="1.3.31">
    <framework src="src/android/build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
    <framework src="org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.31" />

    <!-- Add Kotlin support -->
    <hook type="after_plugin_add" src="hooks/support-kotlin.js" />
    <hook type="after_platform_add" src="hooks/support-kotlin.js" />

    <apply-plugin>kotlin-android-extensions</apply-plugin>
    <apply-plugin>kotlin-kapt</apply-plugin>

    <!-- Cleanup Kotlin source on uninstall -->
    <hook type="before_plugin_rm" src="hooks/on-uninstall.js" />
    <hook type="before_plugin_uninstall" src="hooks/on-uninstall.js" />

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="MeasurePlugin">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.gj.arcoredraw.MeasurePlugin"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true" />   
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
      <activity android:name="com.gj.arcoredraw.MeasurePluginActivity" android:label="Measure Activity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      </activity>
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />  
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux" android:value="optional" />
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/MeasurePlugin.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/java/cordova/plugin"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/MeasurePluginActivity.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/java/cordova/plugin"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/AnchorInfoBean.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/java/cordova/plugin"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/FaceToCameraNode.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/java/cordova/plugin"/>

    <source-file src="src/android/activity_measureplugin.xml" target-dir="res/layout"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/renderable_text.xml" target-dir="res/layout"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/shape_rect_whtie_18.xml" target-dir="res/drawable"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/ar_last.png" target-dir="res/drawable"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/ar_post.png" target-dir="res/drawable"/>
  </platform>
```

Does anyone know how I can go about running this plugin? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: AR Core is only supported on certain devices ...and `com.google.ar.core` isn't `optional`.